# Angular PWA offline data-entry and insertion into database

Tags: node.js, angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have an angular app connected to nodejs api.
I need the app to work as pwa and the user can fill forms offline. Whenever user comes under internet the form data shoud be inserted into database without need of authentication.
How do I achieve this??

Comment: You must have authentication, otherwise, anybody can spam your API.

Comment: First I have login page after that user can acces the form.

Comment: How do I achieve this in pwa?